# Oracle SQL Query for displaying based on priority

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my query to fetch top five rows based on the priority.
    If there are only two contact_names available - say `name1` and `name2` - I want the output to be `name1,name2,,,` .
    But I am getting `name1,name2`.

How can I get the trailing commas?

```
with cte as ( 
     select pc.person_number 
           ,pc.contact_names 
           ,pc.contact_type 
           ,case when pl.relation='parent' then 'a' 
                 when pl.relation='children' then 'b' 
                 when pl.relation='sibling' then 'c' 
            end as priority 
      from person_contact pc 
          ,person_lookup pl 
     where pc.contact_type=pl.contact_type 
     ) 

    select person_number 
          ,listagg(contact_names,',') 
           WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY priority) contact_name  
      from cte 
    group by person_number
    fetch first 5 rows only
```

Comment: please provide sample data table and expected output

Comment: `name1,name2,,,` and `name1,name2` ..? What's the difference ?

Comment: `LISTAGG()` suppresses trailing delimiters. There is no parameter to override this behaviour. Are you trying to generate a CSV file?

Comment: yes since i have specified 5 rows until 5 contactnames it should display only commas if data is not present @APC

Comment: Note that the `fetch first 5 rows only` limits the **final** result set to five rows. It will not restrict persons with six or more contacts to five contacts.

Comment: Ya i changed it with rownum()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way could be by editing your CTE to give at least the needed number or rows (5 in your example) by adding some empty rows.

In your case, given that you need to build a string, I would simply edit the way you build the string into :

```
listagg(contact_names,',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY priority)
|| rpad(',', 5 - count(*), ',')  contact_name
```